how to make clangd use my custom llvm installation?
I am using clangd from my custom llvm installation, however it still using the system include instead of my installation.
I also tried: export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/my/llvm/include
which does not work. any suggestion here?

Please provide enough information for someone else to reproduce the situation you want help with.  What version of Clang?  How are you running clangd?  What symptom do you see that indicates it is "still using the system include"?

I would suggest in paticular posting clangd logs, they often contain the information needed to diagnose issues like this.
